# Convert quaternion to a line equation

Tags: geometry, quaternions

I have a following set of data:

- Plane equation
- Camera position give an $x$, $y$, $z$
- Camera rotation given as a quaternion

I need to find an intersection of a line going straight ahead from the camera (like a line between current camera position and a point laying in the middle of the field of view is some distance from the camera) and a given plane. Intersection between a line and a plane is simple but how can I obtain an equation of such a line from a quaternion?

Comment: Like Andrei asked: Which way does the camera point at, if there is no rotation? Towards $+z$? $-z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know which way the camera points in the absence of rotation. Say that the direction is ${\bf p}_0=(1,0,0)$. When you rotate this vector by quaternion ${\bf q}$, you get ${\bf p}={\bf q}{\bf p}_0{\bf q}^{-1}$ [(from wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)
The equation of the line is then $(x,y,z)+t{\bf p}=(x,y,z)+t{\bf q}{\bf p}_0{\bf q}^{-1}$ with $t \in\mathbb R$.